# Is new laid sod usually lumpy

Tags: lawn-repair

We just had sod laid about a month ago, Bahia grass. It is so lumpy and bumpy I can’t imagine it will flatten out. It’s nice and green but walking on it is hard. Will it flatten out? And it also has dollar weed throughout.

Comment: In locations with freeze/thaw, it is common to flatten a lawn each spring. A steel roller about 18" + diameter and 4 ' long is weighted with water and pulled over the year with a garden tractor/mower.I expect that is the most practical fix, if you can find one in an area with Bahia grass.

Answer (score 1):

It should not be lumpy and bumpy - if it is, it probably means whoever laid it did not prepare the soil beneath properly,  which should have been levelled out and firmed down a little and any medium to large stones removed. Did it look flat and level when it was first laid? If it did, does it need cutting yet - if it does perhaps the bumpiness is simply because it needs cutting?

Otherwise, try lifting up a strip of sod (round the edge is often easier) which looks particularly bumpy/lumpy - if it hasn't yet rooted into the soil beneath, you should be able to see if there are bumps and hollows or lots of stones in the soil beneath, which would confirm whoever laid it has not done the job properly.

Comment: The problem is that people want "instant lawns". The more time you spend on preparation, and waiting to let the ground settle, the better the end result, but people don't want to look at bare earth for a month, or even longer.

Comment: but if he;s paid someone else to do it, they should have prepped properly as part of the job...